# "could not find implicit ... flash" in invoking nested view template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Note that the problem described in "[flash not found in Products.scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218039/flash-not-found-in-products-scala)" is not the same, and has already been addressed.

The chapter 2 walkthrough in the "Play for Scala" book includes an "editProduct.scala.html" that reads:

```
@(productForm: Form[Product]) (implicit flash:Flash, lang:Lang)
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main(Messages("products.form")){
  ...
  }
}
```

The Play 2.3.8 compiler errors out with:

```
Error:(4, 33) Play 2 Compiler: 
 .../editProduct.scala.html:4: could not find implicit value for parameter flash: play.api.mvc.Flash
 @main(Messages("products.form")){
                             ^
```

I interpret this to mean that for some reason, the "flash" on the first line is not satisfactory for invoking the "main" template on line 4.  The "main" template begins with:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
```

I don't think it's relevant, but the controller code invoking this form reads:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Product
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{mapping,longNumber,nonEmptyText}
import play.api.i18n.Messages

object Products extends Controller {
  ...
  def newProduct = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = if (request.flash.get("error").isDefined)
      productForm.bind(request.flash.data)
    else
      productForm
    Ok(views.html.products.editProduct(form))
  }
  ...
}
```

Can anyone suggest anything to try?  The book is based on Play Framework 2.1, and I'm using 2.3.8, so it might be some kind of version-dependency - but I can't find anything on SO or in the docs that supports that theory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [flash not found in Products.scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218039/flash-not-found-in-products-scala)

Comment: @cchantep - Yes, I saw that too, and indeed had that problem and fixed it - note the "request.flash" in the controller code.  However, I cannot figure out how that problem would map onto the problem at hand.  Do you have a specific suggestion?  For what it's worth, I tried adding the line `implicit val flash = request.flash` in the controller, to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering own post.]  The cause of this problem seems to be that some of the implicit values, such as "flash", are only available implicitly to top-level templates, because they are supplied by some implicit converters in the Controller at the point of invocation.  Since the templates don't inherit from Controller, when they call nested templates these converters are out of scope.

The solution is to explicitly pass in anything that's missing (like "flash") to nested templates that need it.  So the "main" template now begins:

```
@(title: String, flash:Flash)(content: Html)(implicit lang:Lang)
```

I don't know why "lang" works implicitly.  Note that this was a Play-Compiler error, not a Scala-compiler error; that may be a clue.